# Using NavigationManager functionality without integrating Cars App library (androidx.car.app)

Tags: android-automotive

I'm developing a navigation app without the use of templates which are provided by integrating the Android for Cars App Library (https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/car-app).

I want to provide navigation/trip information to the host/system that will be used in the vehicle's cluster and heads-up displays. Using the Cars App Libraries NavigationManager API (https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/car/app/navigation/NavigationManager) you are able to this. But to get reference to NavigationManager you need access to carContext, but in this case you would need to implement template functionality (that is what I don't want).

Is there a way to provide navigation information to the system/host without using NavigationManager (maybe using this API - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/car/Car) or is there a way of including Cars App Library using NavigationManager features but without implementing the template part?